# How C static pointer guards repeating work?

Tags: c, llvm

I'm a C new learner,

when learning llvm,  I met the following code

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sanitizer/coverage_interface.h>


 // This callback is inserted by the compiler as a module constructor
 // into every DSO. 'start' and 'stop' correspond to the
 // beginning and end of the section with the guards for the entire
 // binary (executable or DSO). The callback will be called at least
 // once per DSO and may be called multiple times with the same parameters.
void __sanitizer_cov_trace_pc_guard_init(uint32_t *start, uint32_t *stop) {
  static uint64_t N;  // Counter for the guards.
  if (start == stop || *start) return;  // Initialize only once.
  printf("INIT: %p %p\n", start, stop);
  for (uint32_t *x = start; x < stop; x++)
    *x = ++N;  // Guards should start from 1.
    printf("%p \n", x);
}
```

`static uint64_t N;` matters

Counter for the guards.

without it, the following for loop repeats.

I know what it can do.

#### How does it work ?

---

Here is what the above code prints:

```
INIT: 0x104351508 0x104351544
0x104351508 
0x10435150c 
0x104351510 
0x104351514 
0x104351518 
0x10435151c 
0x104351520 
0x104351524 
0x104351528 
0x10435152c 
0x104351530 
0x104351534 
0x104351538 
0x10435153c 
0x104351540
```

after `uint32_t *x = start;`

why `*x = ++N;` does not change `x`'s position?

Comment: `static` gives the variable a lifetime for the entire program execution. So the variable in this example retains its value across function calls. A non-static variable on the other hand would have a lifetime of just this function and be re-intialised each time (if there were an initialiser which it doesn't in this example).

Comment: updated my question. I don't know pointer well

Comment: "*why *x = ++N; does not change x's position*". It's not clear what you mean. `*x` is the value that `x` points to. There is no way that expression will change `x`. It only changes `*x`.

Comment: Would you mind to elaborate on "_why `*x = ++N;` does not change x's position_", please? Are you asking why `start` or `stop`, which `x` runs over, don't change from call to call?

Comment: You seem to conclude from the output that "`*x = ++N;` does **not** change x's position". Please explain how you arrive at that conclusion, especially with reference to the fact that the loop setup ( `for (uint32_t *x = start; x < stop; x++)` ) **does** change the value of `x`, i.e. the address used within the loop and that by my reading the output confirms that, showing increasing values for the pointer `x`.

Comment: because when `*x = ++N;` removed,  the above printing loops.  And `*x = ++N;` added, the above print once. If `*x = ++N;` does change x's position, i think the output should vary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why `*x = ++N;` does not change x's position?

It seems you are confused about **"the value of a pointer"** and **"the value a pointer points to"** (aka the value of the pointed to object).

The **value** of the pointer `x` is initialized by

```
uint32_t *x = start;
\---------/ \------/
 Defines     Initializes the value of the pointer to equal the value of start
 the 
 pointer x
```

Then the **value** of `x` is changed by this code:

```
x++
```

This part

```
*x = ++N;
```

will **not** change the value of `x`. Instead it change the value of the **pointed to** object.

If you change

```
printf("%p \n", x); --> printf("%p %u\n", x, *x);
```

you'll see output like

```
INIT: 0x104351508 0x104351544
0x104351508 1
0x10435150c 2
0x104351510 3
0x104351514 4
0x104351518 5
0x10435151c 6
0x104351520 7
0x104351524 8
0x104351528 9
0x10435152c 10
0x104351530 11
0x104351534 12
0x104351538 13
0x10435153c 14
0x104351540 15
```

where the first column is **the value of the pointer** `x` and the second column is **the value of the pointed to object**.

In the question you write:

> `static uint64_t N;` matters

> Counter for the guards.

> without it, the following for loop repeats.

It's a bit unclear exactly what you are asking here but using the keyword `static` means that the object `N` preserve its value between calls. In other words, if you call the function again after the example above then `N`  will have the value 15 to start with. So if you provide a new area (i.e. new `start` and `stop` values), you could see something like:

```
INIT: 0x104351600 0x10435160c
0x104351600 16
0x104351604 17
0x104351608 18
```